# Убрать назойливую надпись в админке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Появляется в админке в верхней части страницы.
Спасибо что скачали тему. Купите премиум =)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ее отключил в стилях

```css
.notice.notice-success.is-dismissible {
    background-color: #31a3dd;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

Но хотелось бы вообще в PHP отключить чтобы она вообще не грузилась. 
А то сейчас у меня она просто скрыта.
В какую папку идти. Где копать?
Или как найти функцию которая за вывод такого сообщения отвечает чтобы ее удалить либо отключить..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После совета KAGG Design сделал следующую штуку.

1. Нашел код, который отвечает за вывод этой билиберды.
2. Изменил код в дочерней теме, чтобы при обновлении темы код не изменился.

Итак, рассказываю по порядку.

Качаем всю тему (оригинальную, а не дочернюю на локальный компьютер). У меня стоит программа Sublime Text (бесплатная). С помощью нее открываем папку с темой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда у нас открыт проект, нажимаем комбинацию клавиш ctrl+shift+f чтобы искать текст во всем проекте. Раньше я этого не знал и ходил по всем файлам, а это занимало много времени.

Система нам находит расположения строк.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь видим, где находятся строки и в каком файле.

У меня оказалось, что это отдельная функция, которую нужно переопределить. Конечно, можем удалить, но при обновлении темы все вернется на свои места.

Вот моя функция вместе с хуком:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'guardian_activation_notice' );
function guardian_activation_notice(){
    //wp_register_style( 'custom_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/admin/admin-banner.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_admin_css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('admin',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/core/admin/admin-themes.css');
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible"> 
        <p class="notice-text"><?php 
        $theme_info = wp_get_theme();
            printf( esc_html__('Thank you for installing %1$s - Version %2$s, ', 'guardian'), esc_html( $theme_info->Name ), esc_html( $theme_info->Version ) );        
          echo esc_html__( 'For More info  about Premium Products & offers, Do visit our welcome page.', 'guardian' ); ?></p>
        <p class="notic-gif"><a class="pro" target="_self" href="<?php echo admin_url('/themes.php?page=guardian') ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/theme-gif02.gif"></a></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Я переопределял функцию таким способом.

1. Отвязал функцию от хука, создав новую функцию.
2. Повесил на новый хук альтернативную функцию, в которой удалил целый div, который мне мешал.

Вот код в дочерней теме

```
//Переопределяем родительскую функцию
function remove_guardian_activation_notice(){
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'guardian_activation_notice' );
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'remove_guardian_activation_notice', 0 );

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'guardian_activation_notice_alternate' );
function guardian_activation_notice_alternate(){
    //wp_register_style( 'custom_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/admin/admin-banner.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_admin_css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('admin',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/core/admin/admin-themes.css');
}
?>
```

Вот так я это сделал.

Поскольку я не до конца понимаю тему хуков в WordPress, то если кто-то может пояснить, что можно было укоротить в коде, чтобы сделать его более понятным - было бы хорошо.

Comment: Я бы сделал не так. Вы отменяете `guardian_activation_notice` на `wp_loaded`. Не факт, что в этот момент хук уже определён. Если он не определён, то отмена не сработает. Используйте более низкий приоритет в самой акции `admin_notices`, чтобы отменить хук. Тогда точно сработает: `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'remove_guardian_activation_notice', 0 );`

Comment: В общем, поправил ответ и плюсанул.

Comment: Я вам советую принять свой ответ (отметить галочкой внизу), когда система позволит - т.е. дня через два. Ответ правильный и подробный, он поможет пользователям, которые ищут ответ на похожий вопрос.

Comment: add_action( 'admin_notices', 'remove_guardian_activation_notice', 0 );
А что значит 0 в конце? Дело в том что когда я ноль не вписал то ничего не работает..

Comment: 0 - приоритет акции. по умолчанию - 10. Чем меньше приоритет, тем раньше срабатывает функция. При указании приоритета ниже 10 WordPress вызывает вашу функцию `remove_guardian_activation_notice`  раньше `guardian_activation_notice`, что позволяет вашей функции отменить стандартную. Почитайте документацию о хуках здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/hooks

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

То, что вы сделали - вы убили все admin notices. От любых плагинов, тем и ядра.

Вам надо скачать сайт на локальный компьютер и провести поиск по всем файлам темы на предмет наличия текста "Thank you for installing". Лучше для этого использовать современную IDE типа PhpStorm - там есть индексация файлов, и любой поиск осуществляется мгновенно. Далее изучить код на предмет наличия хуков и отменить вывод через хуки в дочерней теме. Лучше не править основную тему, потому при обновлении ваши правки слетят.